# Why server certificate validation is required at the time of SSL/TLS Renegotition?

Tags: security, ssl, openssl, cryptography, ssl-certificate

why do we need to do server certificate validation at the of SSL renegotiation? thought process behind of my question is that when ssl tunnel is already created and all the handshake would happen through existing tunnel and moreover we already trusted the server then why do need to do the certificate validation again?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Comment: Also checkout the [Triple Handshake attack](https://mitls.org/pages/attacks/3SHAKE).

Answer (score 1):

This is because security certificate status can be changed. For example, the certificate is expired and new revocation information is available and SSL certificate is no longer trusted. And this is one of the reasons why renegotiation is ever used (besides key management questions).

Update:
Server certificate is used only during SSL tunnel negotiation. Once it is done, a symmetric session key is used to protect entire session. Server certificate no longer play a role there until next negotiation.

Comment: Thanks for your Reply... but i am not agree on the reason for renegotiation...  you meant to say that for checking the certificate status we do renegotiation... i guess not ... as far as i understand, renegotiation happens  to increase/change  the security properties(for example better cipher) in mid of session...

Comment: I put key management question in parentheses. Think about renegotiation like new SSL tunnel negotiation (though, some properties are inherited from the current session). As the result, certificate re-evaluation is necessary here.

Comment: lets take the example if client initiate the renegotiation by sending the client hello and handshake again started , why can't we ignore the certificate validation now provided we are aware about the fact that entire renegotiation happens under the tunnel and active attacker don't even know about this since it happens under the tunnel... and whether server expose new or old certificate, we can ignore the cert validation since we already authenticated the server.

Comment: now i come to your question on what if cert is invalidated... but don't you think it is the same case where cert become invalidated soon after the handshake and we can't do anything about it....

Comment: "we can ignore the cert validation sicne we already authenticated the server". We authenticated the server some time ago. Things can be changed. For example, new CRL is avilable and SSL certificate is listed there. As the result we break the trust with the server, because it is compromised.